# Disk Read IO Throttle not showing in perfmon Windows Server 2012 r2

Tags: sql-server, performance

I am working on Windows Server 2012r2,SQL Server 2014.

I am trying to create a new data collector to review Disk IO in perfmon. When I get to the step to add the available counters there is no **Disk Read IO Throttle per sec** in the list to be added.

I did see it in screenshots in other web resources. Is there a way to add it in the perfmon so that it appears as a counter?

Comment: I never heard of that one, do you have a link to some screenshots? you have read write and total IO/sec if that's what you mean. or bytes/sec

Comment: The list of counters available in the [`PhysicalDisk Object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms804035.aspx) is documented. There is no `Disk Read IO Throttle per sec` counter.

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring is not related to windows. It's for [*NIX systems](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/blkio-controller.txt).

For windows, you should monitor

`•\LogicalDisk\Avg. Disk Sec/Read 
•\LogicalDisk\Avg. Disk Sec/Write 
•\LogicalDisk\Disk Bytes/Sec 
•\LogicalDisk\Disk Reads/Sec 
•\LogicalDisk\Disk Writes/Sec 
•\LogicalDisk\Split IO/sec 
•\LogicalDisk\Disk Transfers/sec`

You can use [PAL to analyze the .blg file](https://pal.codeplex.com/) for any bottlenecks.

Check : http://blogs.technet.com/b/cotw/archive/2009/03/18/analyzing-storage-performance.aspx